# How do I copy values from a List<dynamic> obtained from Firebase DocumentSnapshot in Flutter to a new List and add values to it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Create is a stateful widget which receives the postDoc snapshot from another Class.

```
class Create extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot postDoc;

  Create({this.postDoc});

  @override
  _CreateState createState() => _CreateState();
}
```

The postDoc has a 'contributers' field with its type as List

I want to copy the elements in `widget.postDoc['contributers']` and add another element at the last.

The new list will now be used as value "contributers" field in a new post.

How should I copy widget.postDoc['contributer'] and add element to it?

I've already tried,

```
List<dynamic> contributer;
contributer=widget.postDoc['contributers'];
contributer.add(widget.postDoc['username']);
```

but the contributer is now of fixed-length and new element cannot be added.

Comment: How `List<dynamic> contributer` has fixed-length?

Comment: `postDoc` is `DocumentSnapshot`, not `List`.

Comment: The postDoc['contributers'] is of type List<dynamic>.

Comment: It is showing error: ```Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to a fixed-length list``` on adding to contributer.

Comment: Try `contributer.addAll(widget.postDoc['contributers']);`

Answer (score 2):

The `Cannot add to a fixed-length list` can be easily fixed as follows:

```
List<dynamic> contributer = List.from(widget.postDoc.data()['contributers']);
contributer.add(widget.postDoc.data()['username']);
```

`List.from()` returns a growable list & you can add any element to it.

Documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/List/List.from.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using a fixed-length list (which is good for performance overall) but, in you use case you need a growable list. `List<T> list = List();`

So do the following.

```
List<dynamic> contributor = List();

contributor.addAll(widget.postDoc.data()['contirbutors']);
contributor.add(widget.postDoc.data()['username']);
```

Using the assignment operator as you did, a fixed list operator is created with a size equal to the size of the list to be assigned.

**Example of Fixed-length vs Growable length list**

```
void main(){
//define list with fixed length
var myList = List(3);

//assign list with items
myList = [25, 63, 84];

print(myList);
}
```

This is a growable list.

```
void main(){

var myList = List();

myList.add(25);
myList.add(63);
myList.add(84);

print(myList);
}
```

PS: You are should applying best practices which coding for install you should separate your `business logic` from your `presentation`.